# What format of file is .vimrc?

Tags: vim

.vimrc is the configuration file for vim, but I have a doubt..

What kind of file is? what is the language inside of it?

Comment: See `:help vimrc-intro` for a nice introduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just Vim commands in a text file.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the article: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file

> The vimrc file contains optional runtime configuration settings to
>   initialize Vim when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

.vimrc is a file which is used for pre configuration of our scripting code. If we want to set some pre configurations we can declare in that file. The language used in it is generally a scripting language (shell scripting).